# Loop in Java that takes 2 values in from the String

Tags: java, string, loops, input, delimiter

I need to write a loop that takes in two values from the user-given list and then work with those values in the loop. My issue is that I can not seem to get the loop to take in the 2 values from the String. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("enter numbers seperated by commas");
        String numbers = input.nextLine();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(numbers);
        s.useDelimiter(",");
        for(int i =0; i<numbers.length(); i+=2 ) {
            int newnum = i/25;
            System.out.println(newnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using `s` anywhere. You're creating the variable but then ignoring it. It holds the key to your problems -- use it to get your input.

Comment: just `numbers.split(",")`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this in a book... Head First Java, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Here, to get the values - do as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter numbers seperated by commas");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String[] numbers = input.nextLine().split(",\\s*");

    //to read number
    System.out.println(numbers[0] + " - " + numbers[1]);

    //to use them as int
    int i = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
    System.out.println(++i);

}
```